Is this inference sound?
I want to prove the following. From $\vdash \varphi(x)\to \psi$, infer $\vdash \exists x \varphi(x)\to \psi$ given that $x$ doesn't occur free in $\psi$. Here's my reasoning.
Proof. Let $\mathfrak{A}\vDash \varphi(x)\to\psi$. And assume $\mathfrak{A}\vDash \exists x \varphi(x)$. Then $\mathfrak{A}\vDash \varphi(a)$ for some $a\in A$. Since $x$ doesn't occur free in $\psi$, it must be the case that $\mathfrak{A}\vDash \varphi(a)\to \psi$. Now by Modus Ponens, $\mathfrak{A}\models \psi$. Hence $\mathfrak{A}\vDash \exists x\varphi(x)\to \psi$.
Is this proof correct? Or is it complete nonsense?

Yes, that's right. What part seems unconvincing to you?

Thanks, I just wanted to make sure that my reasoning is correct.
